# Matplotlib- creating a stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe that contains data on multiple people in multiple countries. All I'm looking to do is to create a stacked bar chart for each person, separated by country.

What my data looks like:

```
 person   country    sector     ex_sector  
 jim      US             0.25   0.3333333  
 tim      US        0.3333333         0.2  
 john     US              0.9         0.9  
 tom      US              0.2        0.25  
 jim      UK             0.25   0.3333333  
 tim      UK        0.3333333         0.4  
 john     UK              0.1         0.1  
 tom      UK              0.4        0.25  
 jim      JP              0.5   0.3333333  
 tim      JP        0.3333333         0.4  
 john     JP                0           0  
 tom      JP              0.4         0.5
```

and so I know that if I just do a `jimchart = df.loc[df['person'] == 'jim']` I can get:

```
 person   country   sector   ex_sector  
 jim      US          0.25   0.3333333  
 jim      UK          0.25   0.3333333  
 jim      JP           0.5   0.3333333
```

This is what the end goal should be:

[image]

What is the most efficient way to do this? When I try just plotting the sector column, it simply just plots each country on its own bar and doesn't stack them.

From other documentation it seems like I have to pivot my table so that each country has its own column- that would make my table much wider (I'm using an example, my real df has like 10 countries). Appreciate the help!

Comment: What's wrong about having 10 columns?

Comment: is that the only way to do it? thought matplotlib would be more dynamic.... so should I just stack my df?

Comment: I'm actually pretty confused- how do you think I should approach this? setting each country to be a column?

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to do it, `jimchart.pivot_table(columns='country').plot.bar(stacked=True)` is just a concise and idiomatic way to do it with pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [61]: df.groupby('country')[['sector','ex_sector']].sum().T
Out[61]:
country          JP        UK        US
sector     1.233333  1.083333  1.683333
ex_sector  1.233333  1.083333  1.683333

In [62]: df.groupby('country')[['sector','ex_sector']].sum().T.plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0)
```

[image]